# Ajax update panel not letting javascript to work form server side?

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax

Whenever i try to call a javascript function from code behind file, it is not functional.

The root cause is Ajax update panel.

I have tried all the common solution like using `ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript` and other but still not functional.

Below is my code:

```
 protected void GridView2_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
 {
     GridView gvTemp = (GridView)sender;
     gvUniqueID = gvTemp.UniqueID;               
     gvTemp.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex;
     GridViewRow gvParentRow = gvTemp.Parent.Parent as GridViewRow;
     GridView parent = (GridView)gvParentRow.NamingContainer;
     int taskid = Convert.ToInt32(parent.DataKeys[gvParentRow.RowIndex].Value.ToString());
     var lstTaskSheets = (List<Entities.TaskSheetManagement>)Session["CurrentUserTaskSheets"];
     List<Entities.WorkDone> lstWorkdone = lstTaskSheets.Where(x=>x.TaskSheetId == taskid).SelectMany(c => c.WorkDones).ToList();              
     gvTemp.DataSource = lstWorkdone;
     gvTemp.DataBind();
     UpdatePanelGridView.Update();
     string id = "div"+ taskid.ToString();
     ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page,this.Page.GetType(), "Expand", "<script type='text/javascript'>expandcollapse('div" + taskid.ToString() + "','one');</script>",false);

     //  ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page, this.GetType(), "message", "expandcollapse(" + id + ",alt)", false); //Ihave also tried this
 }
```

Javascript code is:

```
function expandcollapse(obj, row) {
    var div = document.getElementById(obj);
    var img = document.getElementById('img' + obj);

    if (div.style.display == "none") {
        div.style.display = "block";
        if (row == 'alt') {
            img.src = "../../img/minus.gif";
        }
        else {
            img.src = "../../img/minus.gif";
        }
        img.alt = "Close to view other Customers";
    }
    else {
        div.style.display = "none";
        if (row == 'alt') {
            img.src = "../../img/plus.gif";
        }
        else {
            img.src = "../../img/plus.gif";
        }
        img.alt = "Expand to show Orders";
    }
}
```

and update panel is used like

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanelGridView" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional" >
```

Anyone help please!!!

Comment: Did you check for javascript errors? I've tested the Jscript with RegisterStartupScript - should work within an update panel. On the other side - are those divs placed in things like a contentPlaceholder or a Gridview? If so, check your client ids - usually Placeholder/Gridviews add a prefix to control ids

Comment: @therak The divs are placed inside grid view

Comment: check your sourcecode on client side and check if the returned id is really in the DOM / call your jscript function from browser console and see if something happens. E.g. your gridview has the id **gv1** - the control you add has the id **TB1** . This would result in a client id something like **gv1_TB1** for the actual control.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use the `<script>` tags like below :

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page,this.Page.GetType(), "Expand", "<script type='text/javascript'>expandcollapse('div" + taskid.ToString() + "','one');</script>",false);
```

Replace the arguement:

```
"<script type='text/javascript'>expandcollapse('div" + taskid.ToString() + "','one');</script>"
```

With below:

```
"expandcollapse('div" + taskid.ToString() + "','one');"
```

The ScriptManager is smart enough to append the script tags.

Hope this helps.

Comment: The last argument of the `RegisterStartupScript` method specifies if script tags should be added. In this case is `false` and they are included in the script.